# Images from public folder suddenly not showing in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am currently making a website for a client, and currently working on a feature for an admin dashboard to add events.

I put all my images in the public folder of the laravel project, in a folder named 'images', (e.g images/img1.jpg)

All of a sudden, when I made a new view and tried to insert my navbar there like so

create.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')

  @include('components.navbar')

@endsection
```

For reference, here is another view that I made which works completely fine
jadwal.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')
  @include('components.navbar')
  <div class='hero flex d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center'>
    <img class='section-bg' src="images/cross.jpg" alt="foto gereja">  
    <h1>ACARA</h1>
  </div>
  <div class='container-fluid flex d-flex flex-column p-3'>
    @foreach ($events as $event)
      <div class='event mt-3 p-3 container md-rounded d-flex flex flex-column'>
        <h3 class=' mb-4 fw-bold'>{{$event->event_title}}</h3>
        {{$event->event_date}}
        <p>{{$event->event_time}}</p>
      </div>
    @endforeach
  </div>
  @include('components.footer')
@endsection
```

and here is the master layout

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <script defer src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js'> </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-z3gLpd7yknf1YoNbCzqRKc4qyor8gaKU1qmn+CShxbuBusANI9QpRohGBreCFkKxLhei6S9CQXFEbbKuqLg0DA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
  <title>Gereja Isa Almasih </title>
</head>
<body>
  @yield('content')
</body>
</html>
```

this is my project folder structure
[image]

and these are the displays side by side (broken vs working)

What could possibly be the cause of this, and how do i fix it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You're in a subfolder `events`, the `images` folder most likely doesn't exist there. As always with these subfolder problems try prepending a slash to your folder, so the webserver starts from the "top/DocumentRoot": `src="/images/cross.jpg"` (Why not use Laravel's asset helpers?)

Comment: the buggy view I sent is not in any subfolder currently, and when i tried your suggestion nothing happened. As for why I dont use it, whenever I tried to use the asset helpers it ends up bugging out and doesnt show anything, assuming you were talking about asset(). @brombeer

Comment: `src="/images/cross.jpg"` _has to_ work (unless you have funky rewrite rules in place). Maybe CTRL-refresh or run `php artisan view:clear`. Did you check the urls of the images on that page? What version of Laravel? How do you serve your files, Apache/artisan/nginx? Are the images missing on other pages too?

Comment: As for your CSS/styling problem, same applies here: `href="/css/app.css"` instead of `href="css/app.css"` or use the asset helper

Comment: @brombeer thanks mate, your comments helped fix the issue. Have a good day!

Comment: Glad it works! 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must use the `asset` function to get the correct path to the images

```php
<img class="section-bg" src="asset('images/cross.jpg')" alt="foto gereja">
```

Comment: sorry, It still didnt work for me. Do you have any other ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: sorry again, but I just tried it out properly and it worked. However, the styling i set in the css didnt apply to it any longer. Any ideas how to fix it? @Denis Sinyukov

Comment: @KevinH that `css/app.css`, use `asset('css/app.css')` too.